# Redirect users after failed login attempt?

Tags: login

I have a custom log-in form and here is the intro to that script:

```
<?php
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $args = array(
            'redirect'          => site_url( '/index.php/portal' ), 
            'form_id'           => 'loginform-custom',
            'label_username'    => __( 'Username' ),
            'label_password'    => __( 'Password' ),
            'label_log_in'      => __( 'Log in' ),
            'remember'          => true
        );
?>
```

When the user makes a failed log-in attempt, they are taken to the WordPress-themed log-in page. How do I keep them on my themed log-in page or direct them to another page?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return to the home page of the site, use

```
site_url()
```

If you want to return to a specific page or post, and assuming that that page/post is http://yoursite.com/this-is-my-post , then you would want to use

```
site_url('/this-is-my-post')
```

If your page name is 'portal', then

```
site_url('/portal')
```

See documentation here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url for some basic examples.